# How do I set up a macro where it will do the following actions each time

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm a complete newbie here and am stuck with a task I have to repeat over the next few days. I would very much appreciate your kind help.
Thanks so much in advance.

**Setup:**

- There are 2 sheets.
- On Sheet1, there is a bunch of data.
- On Sheet2, there is a data table with the same format as in sheet1, but the table is empty.

.

**Desired actions:**

1. Go to the first row of the data table in Sheet1.
2. If the value of the most right column of that row is "1", copy the whole row. If not, go to the next row and check again. Repeat this until something is copied.
3. Go to the first empty row of the data table in Sheet2. Paste values of what was just copied.
4. Return to 1. but start from where you left off. Repeat the whole thing until all data with said condition in Sheet1 has been copied over to Sheet2.

**Progress:**

The recorded macro script I got when I tried by mimicking the above.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

---

```
Sub Macro7()                 ' ' Macro7 Macro '

Range("E11:R11").Select
Selection.Copy Sheets("v4 r2").Select
Range("E11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E12").Select Sheets("v4 q2").Select
Range("E12:R12").Select Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy Sheets("v4 r2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E13").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have your tried Researching and posting what you have tried. With some examples?

Comment: Hi there. I tried by recording the actions in excel, but the conditional move was hard to express..

Comment: Please share what you've already achieved. Please don't reply in comment, but edit your question.

Comment: Hope this makes sense...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - I tried to stick to your recorded macro, but keeping in mind we want to [Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), and use a variable or two to keep track of the next empty row.

```
Sub t()
Dim lastCol&, lastRow&, emptyRow&, i&
Dim mainWS As Worksheet, copyToWS As Worksheet

' Create two variables to hold the sheets
Set mainWS = Sheets("v4 q2")
Set copyToWS = Sheets("v4 r2")

emptyRow = 1

'Now, let's find the last column in the mainWS, and last row
lastCol = mainWS.Cells(1, mainWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = mainWS.Cells(mainWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' assuming your column A (1) has the most data

' Now, loop through your last Column, looking for `1`
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If mainWS.Cells(i, lastCol).Value = "1" Then
       ' Since you only want the VALUES, we can just set the two ranges equal to eachother
       ' instead of using .Copy
       copyToWS.Range(copyToWS.Rows(emptyRow), copyToWS.Rows(emptyRow)).Value = mainWS.Range(mainWS.Rows(i), mainWS.Rows(i)).Value
    emptyRow = emptyRow + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Also, note that since you wanted only the values, we can just set the ranges equal, instead of copying/pasting (which uses the clipboard and can take some more time).  To do that, it's just `Range[destination].Value = Range[the range to copy].Value`.

Comment: wow this is so clear and amazing. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisRyuYamamoto - Yay! If this worked for you, do you mind flagging as the answer? (Click the check mark left of the post).